# US arrest data in 2010 by race and county

Tags: data-request, crime

Can some help locate me to where arrest data in 2010 by county and race of arrestee is available? I've been looking at FBI Crime Statistics data but haven't had much luck so far. However, a paper i've read has mentioned that this data is available from the FBI's UCR data.

Answer (score 2):

This link is to the FBI's UCR data on crime statistics (2010) broken down by race and gender

http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/crime-in-the-u.s/2010/crime-in-the-u.s.-2010/persons-arrested/persons-arrested

This link shows a subset of the tables where the data is broken down by cities and counties.

http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/crime-in-the-u.s/2010/crime-in-the-u.s.-2010/persons-arrested/browse-by/cities-and-counties-grouped-by-size-population-group

This is the home page for all UCR datasets:

http://www.fbi.gov/stats-services/crimestats

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the National Incident-Based Reporting System ([NIBRS](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/NIBRS/)).

As the name suggests, the unit of analysis is the incident itself. It offers many different types of data. Data based on the arestee, the victim (if any), the incident.

I am pretty sure it offers FIPS state-county codes too.

Answer (score 1):

this R program will auto-download the entire collection of microdata, and make it easy for you to analyze it.  good luck!

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20incident-based%20reporting%20system%20%28nibrs%29

Answer (score 1):

data for virginia is compiled in an annual report by the state police, which i've been liberating from pdfs for a little while now. race and arrest data for 2010 in the commonwealth are here:
https://github.com/jalbertbowden/va-crime/tree/master/2010